Add icon uploader in custom tab of WooCommerce admin section
I wrote code to add a custom tab in the WooCommerce setting section page:
add_filter('woocommerce_settings_tabs_array', array($this, 'my_custom_settings_tabs_array'), 99);
add_action('woocommerce_settings_my_custom', array($this, 'action_woocommerce_settings_my_custom'), 10);
add_action('woocommerce_settings_save_my_custom', array($this, 'action_woocommerce_settings_save_my_custom'), 10);

I want to add an image uploader in my custom tab here
public function get_custom_settings()
{
    global $current_section;

    $settings = array();

    // My section 1
    $settings = array(
        // Title
        array(
            'title'     => __('Table Style Setting', ''),
            'type'      => 'title',
            'id'        => 'my_custom_setting_heading'
        ),
        // Text input
        array(
            'title'     => __('Change the text on the top of Table', 'text-domain'),
            'type'      => 'text',
            'desc_tip'  => false,
            'id'        => 'koala_bmsm_general_settings[tb_top_text]',
            'css'       => 'min-width:300px;'
        ),
        // Section end
        array(
            'type'      => 'sectionend',
            'id'        => 'custom_settings_overview'
        ),
    );
    return $settings;
}


You can add the upload field by adding the given code to $settings array.
        array(
            'title'     => __( 'Upload Table Background Image', 'text-domain' ),
            'type'      => 'file',
            'desc'      => __( 'Upload an image for the table background.', 'text-domain' ),
            'id'        => 'koala_bmsm_general_settings[tb_bg_image]',
            'desc_tip'  => false,
        ),

Please let me know if this helps.

It doesn't work because there is no type of file in woocommerce setting.

You need to make some code modifications like below
1. Add new field in $settings array.
array(
    'title'     => __( 'Upload Icon', 'text-domain' ),
    'type'      => 'file',
    'desc'      => __( 'Upload an icon to display in the table header.', 'text-domain' ),
    'id'        => 'koala_bmsm_general_settings[table_icon]',
    'css'       => 'min-width:300px;',
    'default'   => ''
),

2. Create Upload file backend code
<?php

add_action('woocommerce_admin_field_file', 'koala_custom_upload_field');
function koala_custom_upload_field($value)
{
    $option_name = $value['id'];
    $upload_url = get_option($option_name);
?>
    <tr valign="top">
        <th scope="row" class="titledesc">
            <label for="<?php echo esc_attr($option_name); ?>"><?php echo esc_html($value['title']); ?></label>
        </th>
        <td class="forminp forminp-file">
            <input
                id="<?php echo esc_attr($option_name); ?>"
                type="text"
                name="<?php echo esc_attr($option_name); ?>"
                value="<?php echo esc_attr($upload_url); ?>"
                style="<?php echo esc_attr($value['css']); ?>" />
            <button class="button upload_image_button"><?php _e('Upload', 'text-domain'); ?></button>
            <?php if ($upload_url) : ?>
                <p><img src="<?php echo esc_url($upload_url); ?>" style="max-width:150px;" /></p>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <span class="description"><?php echo esc_html($value['desc']); ?></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $('body').on('click', '.upload_image_button', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                var button = $(this),
                    custom_uploader = wp.media({
                        title: '<?php _e('Insert image', 'text-domain'); ?>',
                        library: {
                            type: 'image'
                        },
                        button: {
                            text: '<?php _e('Use this image', 'text-domain'); ?>'
                        },
                        multiple: false
                    }).on('select', function() {
                        var attachment = custom_uploader.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
                        $(button).prev().val(attachment.url);
                    })
                    .open();
            });
        });
    </script>
<?php
}

add_action('woocommerce_settings_save_my_custom', 'koala_save_custom_upload_field');
function koala_save_custom_upload_field()
{
    $settings = get_option('koala_bmsm_general_settings', array());
    if (isset($_POST['koala_bmsm_general_settings'])) {
        foreach ($_POST['koala_bmsm_general_settings'] as $key => $value) {
            $settings[$key] = sanitize_text_field($value);
        }
    }
    update_option('koala_bmsm_general_settings', $settings);
}

